# Does version need to be live to check if TrustManager error is fixed?

Tags: android-security, trustmanager

I'm experiencing the problem

> Your app is using an unsafe implementation of the X509TrustManager
>   interface with an Apache HTTP client, resulting in a security
>   vulnerability. Please see this Google Help Center article for details,
>   including the deadline for fixing the vulnerability.

I needed to break my app's code to (i think) fix the problem. I need to know if the change is working, if so I'll fix the other problems the fix caused. If I upload the build to production using timed publishing but don't make the build live will it tell me if the error affects that build # in the popup error message?

Comment: I submitted a build using timed publishing and after 10+ hours it told me the apk was affected. So you don't have to publish live builds to check if you've fixed the problem in the new apk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Builds submitted using timed publishing will be flagged if they are affected.